How to concatenate an element to vector without inserting it into the vector?
I want to pass a vector into a recursive function after concatenating an element to it, without changing the actual vector.
func(vector<int>nums,int idx,vector<int>){
    func(nums,index+1,arr+nums[idx]);
}

This gives:
Line 12: Char 37: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('vector<int>' and 'value_type' (aka 'int'))
   12 |         func(nums,index+1,arr+nums[index]);
      |                        ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~

I was trying to do something like that, but without changing the arr in the current recursive step.
Not using push_back, emplace_back, and insert, as they will change the arr.

Why? You already copy the vectors in func, what is the problem with modifying that copy?

where is the definition of arr and index?

There is no concatenation in the code shown. What do you think arr+nums[idx] is doing? The error clearly says that arr is a vector and nums[index] is an int. The 3rd parameter of func expects a vector. You can't create a new vector by adding an int to an existing vector using operator+. If you are trying to add the int at  nums[index] to an int in arr then you need to index into arr just like you did with nums. It is not clear what this code is trying to do.

You have misunderstandings about how C++ work, and how containers work in general. Consider reading a good book.

Maybe you can do a push_back before the call, and a pop_back after returning? Will anyone notice?

@RemyLebeau They would like a temporary vector, like "Hello World"s + '!' gives you a temporary string containing Hello World!. Why? I have no idea.

Please post actual code, not a rough approximation.

@Yksisarvinen vector doesn't work that way. If the OP wants arr+nums[idx] to create a new vector with the int added to it, they will need to define their own operator+ to do that.

std::vector does not define an operator+ to concatenate elements.  If you want that, you will have to define your own operator, eg:
vector<int> operator+(std::vector<int> vec, int value) {
    vec.push_back(value);
    return vec;
} 

func(vector<int>nums, int idx, vector<int> arr){
    func(nums, index + 1, arr + nums[idx]);
}

Otherwise, since you are passing your vector objects around by value (the 1st one really should be passed around by reference instead), you are making copies of them anyway, so there is no reason to just modify a copy directly as needed, eg:
func(vector<int> &nums, int idx, vector<int> arr){
    arr.push_back(nums[idx]);
    func(nums, index + 1, arr);
}

